# Convert String in to a function call in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, string, function, button, dynamic

In my case buttons are created dynamically and functions names are assigned to them dynamically. Function names are received from DB. I know it is possible in JS but in reactJS, I couldn't assign my method names to the relevant Button.

Below is my current code

```
{this.state.btnArray.map((btnProps, index) =>
  <button
    key={index}
    onClick={() => this.onButtonClick(btnProps.method)}
    style={btnStyle}
  >
    {btnProps.value}
  </button> 
)}
```

Here `onButtonClick` is the method for all buttons, I want it to change for each button.

Comment: Use unique value as the handler function's params to make the distinction would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your onClick function to call the btnProps.method prop directly

```
{this.state.btnArray.map((btnProps, index) =>
 <button
  key={index}
  onClick={() => btnProps.method()}
  style={btnStyle}
  >
   {btnProps.value}
 </button> 
 )}
```